# How to set DateTime format throughout the entire application in UWP?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp

I'm able to get the DateTime Format for the current culture by using

```
Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatter("shortdate",new[] { "en-US"}, "US", CalendarIdentifiers.Gregorian, ClockIdentifiers.TwelveHour);
```

But I would like to set the DateTime Format, particularly date format as MM/dd/yy.
How can I achieve this throughout the entire application.

Answer (score 0):

> But I would like to set the DateTime Format, particularly date format as MM/dd/yy.

If I understand it correctly. You can change the Format Pattern Template like below:

```
Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter("{month.integer(2)}/{day.integer(2)}/{year.abbreviated}", new[] { "en-US" }, "US", CalendarIdentifiers.Gregorian, ClockIdentifiers.TwelveHour);
```

And it will get the output like: `07/08/16`. For a Format Template Details, you can refer to ***Format pattern field*** of [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.globalization.datetimeformatting.datetimeformatter.aspx).

> How can I achieve this throughout the entire application.

You can store this formatter globally by saving it to `App.Resources` like below:

Inside `OnLaunch` Method of `App.Xaml.cs`:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    var dateFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter("{month.integer(2)}/{day.integer(2)}/{year.abbreviated}", new[] { "en-US" }, "US", CalendarIdentifiers.Gregorian, ClockIdentifiers.TwelveHour);
    this.Resources.Add("dateFormatter", dateFormatter);
    ...
}
```

Then you can get it anywhere in your app through codes like below:

```
var formater = (DateTimeFormatter)App.Current.Resources["dateFormatter"];
var timeStr=formater.Format(DateTime.Now);
```

**Update**:
For `DatePicker` Control, you can manually set the DayFormat, MonthFormat and YearFormat like below:

```
<DatePicker DayFormat="{}{day.integer(2)}" MonthFormat="{}{month.integer(2)}" YearFormat="{}{year.abbreviated(2)}"></DatePicker>
```

And for CalendarDatePicker, you can manually set the DateFormat Property like below:

```
<CalendarDatePicker DateFormat="{}{day.integer(2)}/{month.integer(2)}/{year.abbreviated(2)}" ></CalendarDatePicker>
```

Comment: How do I apply this by default for all DatePicker, CalendarDatePickers?

Comment: You can't set it by default for all DatePickers and CalendarDatePickers. You can only manually set the `DayFormat`,`MonthFormat` and `YearFormat` properties of `DatePickers` and `DateFormat` of `CalendarDatePickers`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Is there any way to arrange them in a particular order? Like MM/dd/yyyy. Cause this by default takes the format from the device.

Comment: As far as I know,currently there is no such way without changing system settings. Unless you want to create your own DatePicker Control.